# Intercept if a field in DB has changed with JAVA by comparing it with it's old value

Tags: java, sql

I have a requirement where if a record is inserted or updated in a db table, then automatically a java process needs to detect it by comparing the old with the new value. What is the easiest way to implement it ?

Comment: *What is the easiest way to implement it?* => Database triggers.

Comment: Is this record upserted by _you_ (the Java process) or some external source?

Comment: It is indeed upserted by my program ! i've got the control over it !

Comment: I can't use triggers unfortunatly in that case, every things need to be done by java process

Comment: You're probably looking for the `INSERT INTO ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE ...` statement, aka upsert. In this case you would need a unique key index, and when you upload something with a matching key, update it instead. E.g. (in rough pseudocode) `INSERT id=1,val=1 ON DUPLICATE val=val+1`

Comment: Are you using JPA? What database are you using?

Comment: I am using JPA a Springboot application with Oracle DB

Answer (score 0):

With JPA you can use the *callback methods*: using `@PrePersist`, `@PreUpdate` and `@PreRemove` in your Entity, or inside a listener associated to your Entity through the `@EventListeners` annotation, you can do some actions just before some DML operations.

Otherwise Spring JPA implements his EventListener and, if this doesn't like, it has own *JPA Auditing* system.

You can find information about it almost everywhere ... one of the first results on google is, for example,  [this](https://www.baeldung.com/database-auditing-jpa).

I'm using Postgres and here we have a mechanism by which, through a trigger, we send information on a jdbc channel (we use it to invalidate the cache) ... I know that Oracle has a similar system, but my know-how stops here: you have to read the  [official documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/java.112/e16548/dbchgnf.htm#JJDBC28815)